# Javascript to slide invisible div from top of the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i've been trying to replicate the functionality of the How it works button of airbnb. I'm new to stackoverflow, so I don't know the policies to link the website.

What I have tried:

My HTML mockup

```
<div class="how-it-works">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
              <span class="pull-right">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="hideHowItWorks()"></span>
              </span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-3">
                      <div class="hiw-container hiw-step-one"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-3">
                      <div class="hiw-container hiw-step-two"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-3">
                      <div class="hiw-container hiw-step-three"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-3">
                      <div class="hiw-container hiw-step-four"></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

```
<div class="main-class">
    ...some content....
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.how-it-works{
    position: absolute
    width: 100%
    top: -663px
    padding-top: 40px
    min-height: 663px
}
```

I'm using JQuery to slide the entire div down instead of using the standard `slideDown procedure`.

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
$('.how-it-works').css('height', $(window).height());
$('.how-it-works').animate({top: '0px'});
$('.main-class').animate({marginTop: '663px'});
})
```

If I use this method or the method of slideDown, the frame while sliding, stutters and gives an effect thats far from pleasing. How do I make the effect that's similar to the above mentioned website?

Comment: where is the link to the website of your expected effect?

Comment: Can you please explain more details of the sliding effects you expect?

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/klickagent/vtwhzm9q/1/

Answer (score 1):

Slide an overlay on canvas from the top. This uses vanilla javascript and css animations. jQuery animations always seems jerky in my opinion.

```js
var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
document.getElementById('open').onclick = function() {
    overlay.style.top = 0;
}
document.getElementById('close').onclick = function() {
    overlay.style.top = '-100%';
}
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#overlay {
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
    transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="close">close</a>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="open">Open</a>
```